# Writing Pose values real time using Opencv to a text file

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi all I am working on camera pose estimation of a moving camera. I would like to store the values of the distance between the camera and marker real time to a text file so that I can validate my algorithm.

So far I tried

```
  std::fstream outputFile;
  outputFile.open( "myFile.txt", std::ios::out );
  outputFile << trans.rows << std::endl;
  outputFile << trans.cols << std::endl;
  for(int c = 0; c<trans.rows; c++)
      {
          for(int j = 0; j < trans.cols; j++)
                  {
                    outputFile << trans.at<float>(c,j)<<std::endl;
                  }
     }
 outputFile.close();


 FileStorage fs("newfile.txt",FileStorage::WRITE);
 while(true)
     fs << "mat1" << x22  ;//the distance value
```

"myfile.txt" gives just one value which is not what I want. I want the value for every frame real time. "newfile.txt" from while loop is alright but the program crashes when I use it.
How do I go about it?

Thank you

Comment: Is the code piece you shared being run every frame?

Comment: Technical details rather than looping on your matrix you can directly do:

    outputFile<<trans<<std::endl;

Another advise try to use a binary file rather than a text file.
The fact `MyFile.txt` does contains only a scalar mean that the variable `trans` does only contains a single scalar. 
Maybe you should take a look to that.

Comment: yes the snippet is under a previous while loop. So it runs every frame.
If that's what you meant. @unlut

Answer (score 0):

First, lets make sure this is not just a c++ problem, instead of override myFile.txt in each frame, just append new information to file. Change from

```
outputFile.open( "myFile.txt", std::ios::out );
```

to

```
outputFile.open( "myFile.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

If problem still occurs I will edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you !! It helped. You saved me a lot of hassle.